# CSS absolute positioning & responsive design

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm building this site and we had the cool idea of overlapping the logo over the navigation bar and slider using absolute positioning. Only problem is, it breaks the theme's responsive nature.

What could I do to have this look without breaking the responsiveness?

Site we are building: http://cohesivehosting.com/create/dukesandwich/

Resize the window yourself and you will see how the logo in say "iPhone like resolution" is now over the responsive menu bar.

Comment: Swap out the round logo for a stylized header with the right text and colors?

Answer (score 0):

In mobile layouts, I would switch from absolute to relative positioning

Comment: That would be awesome actually. How would I go about doing that? Sorry, just new to responsive design.

Comment: Something like `@media all and (max-width: max-size) and (min-width: min-size) {headerelement{position:relative;}}`

Comment: got it... Thanks so much for your help! I think this will work.